# Error encountered while pushing to the remote Git repository

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently working on a project that is hosted on visualstudio.com (Visual studio online) and I choose Git as the code repository but I'm getting a error when I try to push my changes in the code to a Git repository.

When I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to push it I'm getting that error message:

```
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Chunked encoding upload is not supported on the HTTP/1.0 protocol
```

I also have Visual Studio 2013 installed on this machine, and with VS2013 I can push the changes to the repository without any errors.

- **What can I do to solve this problem?**

PS: I'm behind a proxy server. (**I can push the changes via VS2013 throught the *proxy***)

Comment: are you pushing to the same remote? what does `git remote -v` tell you?

Comment: Is there a proxy server in between? It's strange that you're forced to Http/1.0

Comment: @jessehouwing, yes theres a proxy server, but, In VS2013 I can push. The problem is only with VS2015

Comment: @eckes the command says: origin  https://URL (fetch)
origin  https://SameURL (push)

Comment: I suspect it's a limitation of LibGit and was a choice of memory usage and performance to take http/1.1 as minimum supported. Without chunked encoding it would require to send the pack file in one go and requires a lot more memory on the client side.

Comment: And I suspect your proxy server is the culprit.

Comment: @eckes, when you say: "are you pushing to the same remote?". Yuo are saying if my VS2013 and my VS2015 are pushing to the same remote? If yes, yes, both VS are pushing to the same remote.

Comment: @jessehouwing, me and my friend are using the same Internet and even proxy pointing to the same repository / project in visual studio online

Comment: Yes, but Vs2013 uses a different version of LibGit2 than Vs2015. A lot of performance issues have been fixed, so this may cause the new dependency.